# Make holow piece solid

Tags: mesh

to start I know nothing about about 3d modeling so sorry if I am asking something very stupid
I have this piece than is part of bigger model to 3d print than I has able to separate it from on the STL and between this past and the "main body" there are hollow spaces causing problem while 3D printing
I want to make this piece solid or thicker so it would fill those hollow spaces
Note: I only have the STL files
[image: Top]

[image: Bottom]

Answer (score 0):

you can use a solidify modifier to make it thicker.
I think this video will help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9a1Gd74uvw